# How do I filter posts in Rails 4 with a scope based off a nested attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to filter the posts that appear on my index page. I filtered them initially by using this condition in the view:

```
if current_user.courses.any? {|h| h[:name] == post.course.name}
```

But since I added will_paginate, I get blank pages because it paginates even the posts I don't want to show. How can I use a scope to filter out the posts in the controller?

These are my models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :comments
end
```

and

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :major
end
```

and my controller codes

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page =>
  params[:page], :per_page => 1)   
end
```

Comment: Please show your controller codes

Comment: Sorry just posted them, thank you

Comment: You need to make a [join of your tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables).

Answer (score 0):

If your filter contains more than one `courses names`  :

```
def index 
     @posts = Post.joins(:course).where('courses.name in (?)',current_user.courses.map(&:name)).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 1)  
end
```

Comment: Wow! that seems really close to working, only I got an error: undefined method `joins' for ["Electrical Networks", "Physics 3"]:Array Did you mean? join

Comment: Okay thank you, though now it has the error: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Comment: try to run without paginate ?